# Where is the Vimtutor located

Tags: text-editor

Where is this text tutor? I keep finding references to it but only get an empty document when I run it.

Answer (score 1):

The `vim-runtime` package contains the file required for `vimtutor`, according to the [package index](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=tutor%2Ftutor&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any). Install it:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall vim-runtime
```